# Session data lost between two web directories

Tags: jsp, session, gwt, tomcat

Yet I haven't seen solution for this in JSP. So, I have GWT application and JSP welcome and login pages. Thera are two web archives.

- welcome.war
- app.war

The Tomcat has two directories:

- mydomain.com/welcome/
- mydomain.com/app/

In login process in mydomain.com/welcome/login.jsp I set session attributes. When user uses hyperlink to move to mydomain.com/app/app.jsp the session attributes set in login.jsp are lost.

Do you know any way how to persist the values of session attributes?

Thanks Vit

Comment: It seems it has something to do with JSessionId. The value is different in both cases. Does anybody know how to ensure the JSessionId has the same values in both directories?

Comment: Why not have the login pages in the app.war? ( That is how we manage login currently in our gwt app)

Comment: This is worth condidering. It is possibly easier procedure to move all jsp files to the GWT project and build these resouces together. Just for historical reasons we have it stored in different war files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two war that's mean you have two different context. and every context has own session management. but you can share session data between this two context. Refer [link](http://www.fwd.at/tomcat/sharing-session-data-howto.html)